# How to correctly use return statements along with an if else statement?

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, return

if the first condition is false, i would like to return a different read. How would i accomplish this?

```
           if (reader.HasRows == true)
           {

               reader.Read();


               Answers a = new Answers( reader["Correct"].ToString());

               Answer= a;

           }
               return Answer;

           else {

               Answers Answer =  new Answers();
               Answers a = new Answers( reader["Incorrect"].ToString());

               Answer= a;


           }
           return Answer;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple try this. Just need two lines.

```
   if (reader.HasRows == true)
   {
       reader.Read();
       return  new Answers( reader["Correct"].ToString());//return correct if reader return any values
   }              
       return  new Answers( "Incorrect Values" );//return incorrect if reader not return any values           
}
```

or simple try this ternary operators, Do't need any if else conditions.

```
return reader.HasRows == true ? new Answers( reader["Correct"].ToString()):new Answers( "Incorrect Values" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` logic is flawed, in that if `reader` has no rows, then the `else` cannot use the `"Incorrect"` field in the non-existent row, because no data was actually read and the `reader` is empty.

As for your syntax, try this:

```
// Are there any rows returned?
if(reader.HasRows)
{
    // Yes, so read the first row and grab the "Correct" field and return it
    return new Answers(reader["Correct"].ToString());
}

// No data was found
// Return null, because you cannot get to the "Incorrect" field value
return null;
```

---

> Note: Since this returns `null` have your calling code check for `null` so they do not get a `NullReferenceException`.